# Find free port in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to find free port in Qt 5.8. I have written below code which is working fine when proxy server in windows is not configured. if we configured proxy server with "IP address" and "port" then below code is not working and it gives "Operation not permitted" when we bind the socket.

```
QTcpSocket socket;
quint16 port = 0L;
socket.bind(0, QTcpSocket::ShareAddress);
port = socket.localPort();
```

Here "port" will give correct port but when we configured proxy server then it is giving "0" as port number.

Can you please suggest what wrong in above code or alternative to find free port on localhost ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a client, there is no need to actually bind the port (if this is a server, you really do not want to use a random port and you might want to look at QTcpServer). You can use connectToHost(), which will assign you an available source port.